# Use Typescript in some part of the app only

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a node js application.
All the codes are now in javascript.

But in some part of my app I want to use Typescript `Interface` or `enum` options.

How can I use Typescript just for those part of the app?

I don't want to refactor all the project to using Typescript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try Flow [https://flow.org](https://flow.org/)

Flow in opposition to TypeScript isn't a superset or language. It's a static type checker for JavaScript. Because it's not a language, it can be smoothly integrated with JavaScript with a single comment annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a single .ts file, and use plain javascript for the rest of them.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/

> TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain
> JavaScript.
>
> [...] Use existing JavaScript code, incorporate popular JavaScript
> libraries, and call TypeScript code from JavaScript.
>
> TypeScript compiles to clean, simple JavaScript code which runs on any
> browser, in Node.js, or in any JavaScript engine that supports
> ECMAScript 3 (or newer).